# Rename [azure-active-directory] to [azure-ad]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

There are now a few Azure AD products: B2C, B2B, Graph-API.  I think it would be beneficial if all the tags had a consistent prefix.  I think Azure-AD would be the preferred prefix.  Thoughts?

**Current Tags**

- [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory)
- [azure-ad-b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-b2c)
- [azure-ad-b2b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-b2b)
- [azure-ad-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-graph-api)

Comment: [azure-ad] is already a synonym of this tag, so it'll get automatically remapped. Also, it is always preferred to have the expanded version, rather than acronyms.